# onChange method not called with firebase database access

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem in doing a query and reading my firebase database via Java. I'm triyng to save the email of the logged user, but it seems that onChangeMethod is never called.
I've cheched database rules and the sha1 fingerprint in firebase.
Here's the code:

```
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LockerDatabase implements ValueEventListener{
    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    private DatabaseReference reference;

    private User currUser;
    private ArrayList<Password> passwords;

    public int count;

    public LockerDatabase(String email, String name) {
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        reference = database.getReference();

        currUser = new User();
        passwords = new ArrayList<>();

        if (!exists(email))
            createUser(email, name);
        else
            loadPasswords();
    }

    private void loadPasswords() {
        //TODO: read from db all passwords
    }

    public String getEmail(){
        return currUser.getEmail();
    }

    private void createUser(String email, String name) {
        currUser.setEmail(email);
        currUser.setName(name);
        currUser.setHashId(Integer.toString(email.hashCode()));

        //TODO: add user to database
    }

    private boolean exists(String email) {
        Query existence = reference.child("users").child(Integer.toString(email.hashCode()));
        existence.addValueEventListener(this);

        if (currUser == null)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        currUser.setEmail((String)dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.w("CAN", "user_cancelled", databaseError.toException());
    }
```

I'm trying to display the email in an activity, where it appears mi default value and not the correct one:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.locker_layout);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    userEmail = intent.getStringExtra("email");
    userName = intent.getStringExtra("name");

    db = new LockerDatabase(userEmail, userName);

    TextView t = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    t.setText(db.getEmail());

    //TODO: display db results
    //TODO: if the user is new, set an access key
}
```

Here's the database:
[JSON here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfNgr.png)

I don't understand if my problem is due to the response time, or to some error in the code.
Thank you!

Comment: Have you debug or print anything in _Log_ in _onDataChange_?

Comment: Is your `exists()` method triggered? Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @Piyush I've tried to print the same thing on exists() and onDataChange(), it worka only in the first one.

Comment: @AlexMamo the method is called once when the LockerDatabase object is created

Comment: What is the value of "Integer.toString(email.hashCode())"? Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo sorry, I've added a link. I used the hash code of the email as an ID for users

Comment: In short, what is the value of "Integer.toString(email.hashCode())" if you log out?

Comment: I think it would be a nullPointerException because when logging out user value is null. But in this code, the user has already logged in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use `Integer.toString(email.hashCode())` as a child, either use the `push()` method that will generate a random key or use the user `uid` if you are using firebase authentication.

If you use `push()`, then store the key first:

```
String key  = reference.child("users").push().getKey();
```

Then when you want to retrieve data, do the following:

```
Query existence = reference.child("users").child(key);
existence.addValueEventListener(this);
```